# Как снять внутреннее форматирование ячеек в Excel

Tags: excel

При работе с таблицей MS Excel выяснилось, что некоторые ячейки имеют внутреннее форматирование:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использование кисточки (функция "Формат по образцу"), равно как и функции "Условное форматирование" не приводят к результатам. Предполагается использовать данную таблицу для динамической обработки данных в PHP, библиотека RedBeanPHP запинается об это форматирование, и обработка данных крэшится.

Ручной способ замены текста в каждой такой ячейке займёт кучу времени, так как в таблице более 7000 строк. Как системно снять это "внутреннее" форматирование?

Comment: Уточните, что значит "внутреннее форматирование"? Его внешне не видно?

Comment: @vikttur видите активную ячейку в строке 105? До двойного щелчка в поле Шрифт отображается "Calibri", но после двойного щелчка мы видим всё содержимое ячейки, в том числе и красный текст в шрифте "Times New Roman". При использовании кисточки ни "Times" ни красный текст не уходят

Comment: @vikttur я отправил Вам фрагмент таблицы с проблемными ячейками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формат шрифта, заданный в ячейке - это формат, применяемый для всей ячейки. Но!

Можно выделить фрагмент текста и задать ему свой формат. При этом общий формат шрифта ячейки не изменится (но изменится, если выделить не фрагмент, а весь текст).

Как получен формат, показанный в примере?

Пишем любой текст, форматируем по своему усмотрению. Например, всем символам (всему тексту) задаем шрифт `Arial 14`. Завершаем редактирование. На ленте тип шрифта ячейки видим - `Arial 14`.

Копируем другую ячейку со шрифтом `Calibri 11`, выделяем ячейку с нашим тектом, вствляем формат (то же можно сделать "метелочкой" - *Формат по образцу*). При этом вид текста в ячейке не изменится, но общий формат текста станет `Calibri 11`. Если выделить текст в режиме редактирования, на ленте отобразится `Arial 14`.

Лечится просто. Выделить столбец или диапазон ячеек с проблемным форматированием и вручную изменить параметры форматирования - задать формат, размер, цвет.

---

То же можно сделать с помощью небольшого макроса,записанного в общем модуле:

```
Sub FontFormat()
    With Range("B:B").Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 11
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

Применение *VBA* оправдано, если таких замен много или диапазон нужно форматировать частично. Например, выделенный диапазон через одну строку:

```
Sub FontFormat2()
Dim rRng As Range, i As Long
    Set rRng = Selection
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To rRng.Rows.Count Step 2
        With rRng.Rows(i).Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Size = 11
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло)